# How to create pdf file in loop in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I have implemented pdf creation,

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/kalileo/2010/06/08/creating-pdf-files-with-cakephp-and-tcpdf

but in my logic,
there is a link "printAll" then in loop i have to generate invoice pdf many number of times.
so is that possible to create multiple pdf files in one function using loop?

till now i have put logic in ctp file and write logic in foreach loop but still only first's record's pdf is generated.

how can I do that? Is there any other way to do this?

so please anyone can help me??

Thanks in advance..

in generate_invoice.ctp

---

```
<?php
     App::import('Vendor','xtcpdf'); 
     $tcpdf = new XTCPDF();
     $textfont = 'freesans'; 
     $tcpdf->SetAutoPageBreak( false );
     $tcpdf->xheadercolor = array(255,255,255);
     $tcpdf->AddPage();
     $tcpdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
     $tcpdf->SetFont($textfont,'',10);
     $total_records = 0;
     foreach($POdata as $order)
 {
         $po = $order['Orderproduct']['id'];
            $total_records = $total_records + 1;
 }
     if($total_records == 1)
     {  
     $html = <<<EOD
         $po; //and other html 
         EOD;
        $tcpdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html,'', 1, 0, true, '', true);
        echo $tcpdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'D');                                                   
    }
    else if($total_records > 1) 
    {
        foreach($POdata as $order)
        {   
                $po = $order['Orderproduct']['id'];
            $total_records = $total_records + 1;
            $html = <<<EOD
                   $po; //and other html 
            EOD;
            $tcpdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html,'', 1, 0, true, '', true);
           $filename = "PO".$poid.".pdf";
    echo $tcpdf->Output($filename, 'D');
            }
     }
```

and data from controller file to view file is correctly get in $POdata.
so new can you please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes we can do that

use foreach() to repeater objects and based on that data generate the PDF and store at some location and you can make array of the display path of each file

pass this array to the object of the view and you can use that in the view file you can also set as download link

Thanks

Comment: just cut first 8 lines of my code and paste in 'if' and 'else' block, just above the '$html' statement and it's done......