# how to write foreach loop in ctpfile for creating pdf in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am creating pdf file and I have done creating pdf for one product's detail.
i have also completed creating pdf in loop.
I have table structure for displaying information.
so I have to add foreach loop within table structure wrapping  and  tag.
so how do I get it done?
can anyone help me..
Thanks..

```
           'App::import('Vendor','xtcpdf'); 
    $tcpdf = new XTCPDF();
    $textfont = 'freesans'; 
    $tcpdf->SetAutoPageBreak( false );
    $tcpdf->xheadercolor = array(255,255,255);
    $tcpdf->AddPage();
    $tcpdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
    $tcpdf->SetFont($textfont,'',10);   
    $html = <<<EOD
        <table>
   foreach($Orderdata as $odata)  //this I want to do
   {
            <tr>
              <td> $odata['tablename']['fieldname']  //i am not able to access this variable like this
              </td> $odata['tablename']['fieldname']
              <td> 
              </td>
           </tr>
 }
          </table>

             '
     ///  code for outputting
```

Comment: go throw with this conservation

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377226/how-to-create-pdf-file-in-loop-in-cakephp/9377362#9377362

Answer (score 0):

yes we can do that

use foreach() to repeater objects and based on that data generate the PDF and store at some location and you can make array of the display path of each file

pass this array to the object of the view and you can use that in the view file you can also set as download link

like foreach loop and set your code in that

Thanks