# How to send a pdf file as attachment in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, email-attachments

I am using cake php 2.0 version, I need to send a PDF attached email once clicked on survey button in my application?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried so far ? did you at least tried to find solution by your own ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

First of all, you should ensure the class is loaded using App::uses():

```
<?php
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
```

in your function/action:

```
$email = new CakeEmail();

$email->attachments('/full/file/path/file.pdf') 
$email->to      = 'em...@email.co.uk';
$email->subject = 'Something';
$email->replyTo = $client['Client']['email'];
$email->from    = $client['Client']['email'];
$email->emailFormat = 'html';

if($email->send()){
  die('Email Sent!');
}else{
  die('Failed to send email');
}
```

Comment: thanks, but same time i need to generate new pdf and then send a mail.can it is possible??

Comment: yes but for that you have to use any pdf file creator library

Comment: check this link for more detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377226/how-to-create-pdf-file-in-loop-in-cakephp

Comment: Thanks thats what i was having doubt..!! now i can do it..!! thanks all

Comment: Hello stackoverflow i am banned for posting question,As i am new to this site, please help me give me one more chance..